# Call t4 Template from Win form and pass parameters in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, t4

Very first time I am developing a utility using T4 to generate .aspx, .aspx.cs files as well as stored procedures. For that I need to pass some parameters like tablename, pagename etc. from windows form to the T4 template. And I have written templates and also a customHost as given http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126579.aspx to call from windows form. Now I can call T4 template from windows form, but I don't know how to pass parameters to T4 template. I have tried to create property in template and call template from Win form but it gives me error on this line "var sessionHost = (ITextTemplatingSessionHost) this.Host;" because I use CustomHost. Please help me out.

Here is the code sample for T4 Template

```
    Text Template Host Test

<#@ template debug="true" #>
<#@ parameter name="MyParameter" type="System.String" #>

<# for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
   {

       WriteLine("This is a test");       
   } 
#>
Parameter in statement block: <# Write(MyParameter); #>
```

CustomHost.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.IO;

namespace FormGenerator
{
    class CustomHost : ITextTemplatingEngineHost
    {
        //the path and file name of the text template that is being processed
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        internal string TemplateFileValue;
        public string TemplateFile
        {
            get { return TemplateFileValue; }
        }
        //This will be the extension of the generated text output file.
        //The host can provide a default by setting the value of the field here.
        //The engine can change this value based on the optional output directive
        //if the user specifies it in the text template.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        private string fileExtensionValue = ".txt";
        public string FileExtension
        {
            get { return fileExtensionValue; }
        }
        //This will be the encoding of the generated text output file.
        //The host can provide a default by setting the value of the field here.
        //The engine can change this value based on the optional output directive
        //if the user specifies it in the text template.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        private Encoding fileEncodingValue = Encoding.UTF8;
        public Encoding FileEncoding
        {
            get { return fileEncodingValue; }
        }
        //These are the errors that occur when the engine processes a template.
        //The engine passes the errors to the host when it is done processing,
        //and the host can decide how to display them. For example, the host 
        //can display the errors in the UI or write them to a file.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        private CompilerErrorCollection errorsValue;
        public CompilerErrorCollection Errors
        {
            get { return errorsValue; }
        }
        //The host can provide standard assembly references.
        //The engine will use these references when compiling and
        //executing the generated transformation class.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        public IList<string> StandardAssemblyReferences
        {
            get
            {
                return new string[]
                {
                    //If this host searches standard paths and the GAC,
                    //we can specify the assembly name like this.
                    //---------------------------------------------------------
                    //"System"

                    //Because this host only resolves assemblies from the 
                    //fully qualified path and name of the assembly,
                    //this is a quick way to get the code to give us the
                    //fully qualified path and name of the System assembly.
                    //---------------------------------------------------------
                    typeof(System.Uri).Assembly.Location
                };
            }
        }
        //The host can provide standard imports or using statements.
        //The engine will add these statements to the generated 
        //transformation class.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        public IList<string> StandardImports
        {
            get
            {
                return new string[]
                {
                    "System"
                };
            }
        }
        //The engine calls this method based on the optional include directive
        //if the user has specified it in the text template.
        //This method can be called 0, 1, or more times.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        //The included text is returned in the context parameter.
        //If the host searches the registry for the location of include files,
        //or if the host searches multiple locations by default, the host can
        //return the final path of the include file in the location parameter.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public bool LoadIncludeText(string requestFileName, out string content, out string location)
        {
            content = System.String.Empty;
            location = System.String.Empty;

            //If the argument is the fully qualified path of an existing file,
            //then we are done.
            //----------------------------------------------------------------
            if (File.Exists(requestFileName))
            {
                content = File.ReadAllText(requestFileName);
                return true;
            }
            //This can be customized to search specific paths for the file.
            //This can be customized to accept paths to search as command line
            //arguments.
            //----------------------------------------------------------------
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        //Called by the Engine to enquire about 
        //the processing options you require. 
        //If you recognize that option, return an 
        //appropriate value. 
        //Otherwise, pass back NULL.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        public object GetHostOption(string optionName)
        {
            object returnObject;
            switch (optionName)
            {
                case "CacheAssemblies":
                    returnObject = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    returnObject = null;
                    break;
            }
            return returnObject;
        }
        //The engine calls this method to resolve assembly references used in
        //the generated transformation class project and for the optional 
        //assembly directive if the user has specified it in the text template.
        //This method can be called 0, 1, or more times.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public string ResolveAssemblyReference(string assemblyReference)
        {
            //If the argument is the fully qualified path of an existing file,
            //then we are done. (This does not do any work.)
            //----------------------------------------------------------------
            if (File.Exists(assemblyReference))
            {
                return assemblyReference;
            }
            //Maybe the assembly is in the same folder as the text template that 
            //called the directive.
            //----------------------------------------------------------------
            string candidate = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(this.TemplateFile), assemblyReference);
            if (File.Exists(candidate))
            {
                return candidate;
            }
            //This can be customized to search specific paths for the file
            //or to search the GAC.
            //----------------------------------------------------------------
            //This can be customized to accept paths to search as command line
            //arguments.
            //----------------------------------------------------------------
            //If we cannot do better, return the original file name.
            return "";
        }
        //The engine calls this method based on the directives the user has 
        //specified in the text template.
        //This method can be called 0, 1, or more times.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public Type ResolveDirectiveProcessor(string processorName)
        {
            //This host will not resolve any specific processors.
            //Check the processor name, and if it is the name of a processor the 
            //host wants to support, return the type of the processor.
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------
            if (string.Compare(processorName, "XYZ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                //return typeof();
            }
            //This can be customized to search specific paths for the file
            //or to search the GAC
            //If the directive processor cannot be found, throw an error.
            throw new Exception("Directive Processor not found");
        }
        //A directive processor can call this method if a file name does not 
        //have a path.
        //The host can attempt to provide path information by searching 
        //specific paths for the file and returning the file and path if found.
        //This method can be called 0, 1, or more times.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public string ResolvePath(string fileName)
        {
            if (fileName == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("the file name cannot be null");
            }
            //If the argument is the fully qualified path of an existing file,
            //then we are done
            //----------------------------------------------------------------
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                return fileName;
            }
            //Maybe the file is in the same folder as the text template that 
            //called the directive.
            //----------------------------------------------------------------
            string candidate = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(this.TemplateFile), fileName);
            if (File.Exists(candidate))
            {
                return candidate;
            }
            //Look more places.
            //----------------------------------------------------------------
            //More code can go here...
            //If we cannot do better, return the original file name.
            return fileName;
        }
        //If a call to a directive in a text template does not provide a value
        //for a required parameter, the directive processor can try to get it
        //from the host by calling this method.
        //This method can be called 0, 1, or more times.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public string ResolveParameterValue(string directiveId, string processorName, string parameterName)
        {
            if (directiveId == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("the directiveId cannot be null");
            }
            if (processorName == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("the processorName cannot be null");
            }
            if (parameterName == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("the parameterName cannot be null");
            }
            //Code to provide "hard-coded" parameter values goes here.
            //This code depends on the directive processors this host will interact with.
            //If we cannot do better, return the empty string.
            return String.Empty;
        }
        //The engine calls this method to change the extension of the 
        //generated text output file based on the optional output directive 
        //if the user specifies it in the text template.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void SetFileExtension(string extension)
        {
            //The parameter extension has a '.' in front of it already.
            //--------------------------------------------------------
            fileExtensionValue = extension;
        }
        //The engine calls this method to change the encoding of the 
        //generated text output file based on the optional output directive 
        //if the user specifies it in the text template.
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void SetOutputEncoding(System.Text.Encoding encoding, bool fromOutputDirective)
        {
            fileEncodingValue = encoding;
        }
        //The engine calls this method when it is done processing a text
        //template to pass any errors that occurred to the host.
        //The host can decide how to display them.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void LogErrors(CompilerErrorCollection errors)
        {
            errorsValue = errors;
        }
        //This is the application domain that is used to compile and run
        //the generated transformation class to create the generated text output.
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        public AppDomain ProvideTemplatingAppDomain(string content)
        {
            //This host will provide a new application domain each time the 
            //engine processes a text template.
            //-------------------------------------------------------------
            return AppDomain.CreateDomain("Generation App Domain");
            //This could be changed to return the current appdomain, but new 
            //assemblies are loaded into this AppDomain on a regular basis.
            //If the AppDomain lasts too long, it will grow indefintely, 
            //which might be regarded as a leak.
            //This could be customized to cache the application domain for 
            //a certain number of text template generations (for example, 10).
            //This could be customized based on the contents of the text 
            //template, which are provided as a parameter for that purpose.
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating;
using System.IO;
using FormGenerator;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;




namespace FormGenerator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessTemplate("Path\\TestTemplate.tt");
        }
        static void ProcessTemplate(string templateFileName)
        {

            if (templateFileName == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("the file name cannot be null");
            }
            if (!File.Exists(templateFileName))
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("the file cannot be found");
            }
            CustomHost host = new CustomHost();
            Engine engine = new Engine();
            host.TemplateFileValue = templateFileName;
            //Read the text template.
            string input = File.ReadAllText(templateFileName);
            //Transform the text template.

            string output = engine.ProcessTemplate(input, host);
            string outputFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(templateFileName);
            outputFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(templateFileName), outputFileName);
            outputFileName = outputFileName + "1" + host.FileExtension;
            File.WriteAllText(outputFileName, output, host.FileEncoding);

            foreach (CompilerError error in host.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I have tried but gives error "Unable to cast object of type 'FormGenerator.CustomHost' to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.ITextTemplatingSessionHost'."

```
 CustomHost Host = new CustomHost();
  Host.TemplateFileValue = templateFileName;
  string templateFile = Host.ResolvePath("TestTemplate.tt");
  string templateContent = File.ReadAllText(templateFile);

  TextTemplatingSession session = new TextTemplatingSession();
  session["MyParameter"] = "SessionValue";

  var sessionHost = (ITextTemplatingSessionHost)Host;
  sessionHost.Session = session;

  Engine engine = new Engine();
  string generatedContent = engine.ProcessTemplate(templateContent, Host);
```

Please help me out how can I resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your CustomHos class serializable

```
[Serializable()]
class CustomCmdLineHost : ITextTemplatingEngineHost
{
}
```